# geoJSON in Leaflet: Displaying features that match values in a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter, leaflet

I hope the answer isn't too obvious, but I am fairly new to both Javascript and Leaflet.

I have been working on this problem for a few days. I have a geoJSON file that I've added to my map as a point layer--now I want to select a subset of those points to display, based on whether a feature's value in the OBJECTID field shows up in an array that I define.

So far, I have been able to select a single point to display by hardcoding the OBJECTID value into my function, as follows:

```
L.geoJSON(co_schools,{filter: schoolFilter}).addTo(mymap);

function schoolFilter (layer) {
    if (layer.properties.OBJECTID===3955) return true;
};
```

And I've been able to select multiple points to display if I define my array *within* the function, like this:

```
L.geoJSON(co_schools,{filter: schoolFilter}).addTo(mymap);

function schoolFilter (layer) {
    idlist = [3955, 5298, 5299];
    for (i=0; i<idlist.length; i++) {
        if (layer.properties.OBJECTID===idlist[i]) return true;
    }
};
```

But I get the following error when I try to pass in an array as a parameter: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at Object.schoolFilter [as filter]**

```
L.geoJSON(co_schools,{filter: schoolFilter}).addTo(mymap);
idlist = [3955, 5298, 5299];

schoolFilter(layer, idlist);

function schoolFilter (layer, list) {
    for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        if (layer.properties.OBJECTID===list[i]) return true;
    }
};
```

I *can* pass the array in if I define it before I run my L.geoJSON command (below), but then I get this error message: **Cannot read property 'OBJECTID' of undefined at schoolFilter**

```
function schoolFilter (layer, list) {
    for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        console.log(list);
        if (layer.properties.OBJECTID===list[i]) return true;
}
};

idlist = [3955, 5298, 5299];

L.geoJSON(co_schools,{filter: schoolFilter(co_schools, idlist)}).addTo(mymap);
```

I'd love any help or advice you might have--thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we always want to define function (eg. `schoolFilter()`) before we use it. Now `filter` options expect a function with specific signature, so we should not change it (eg. by adding more argument). You may want to declare a global variable (in this case `list`) and read it from the function:

> you can click **Run code snippet** to see this code in action!

```js
const mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 15);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1,
  accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw'
}).addTo(mymap);

var popup = L.popup();
mymap.on('click', function(e) {
  popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent(e.latlng.toString())
    .openOn(mymap);
});

// dummy data
const co_schools = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 1
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.092697, 51.504041]
      },
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 2
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.097332, 51.503213]
      },
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 3
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.085702, 51.505938]
      },
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 4
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.086989, 51.50332]
      },
    },
  ],
};

// your code starts here

// var list = [1, 2, 3, 4];    
var list = [1, 2, 3]; // try filtering 4

function schoolFilter(layer) {
  return list.includes(layer.properties.OBJECTID)
}

L.geoJSON(co_schools, {
  filter: schoolFilter
}).addTo(mymap);
```

```css
#mapid {
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<div id="mapid"></div>
```